# Dynamically display a textbox or dropdown based on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

In my html page, I have a Dropdown which contains 2 values - Name and Gender

If the User selects 'Name' in the dropdown, then a textbox (default control) is displayed to allow entry of free flowing text.

However if the User selects 'Gender' in the dropdown, then a dropdown is displayed to allow user to select from 2 values - Male and Female.

Basically I need to have a toggle functionality developed between a textbox and dropdown in Typescript/Javascript to implement this. With my limited knowledge in Javascript, I have tried multiple solutions without any success. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple demo:

```js
$("#switch").change(function () {
  switch($("#switch").val()) {
    case "name":
      $("#name-input").css("display", "inline")
      $("#gender-dropdown").css("display", "none")
      break
    case "gender":
      $("#name-input").css("display", "none")
      $("#gender-dropdown").css("display", "inline")
      break
    default:
      $("#gender-dropdown").css("display", "none")
      $("#name-input").css("display", "none")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="switch">
<option value="unknown"></option>
<option value="name">Name: </option>
<option value="gender">Gender: </option>
</select>
<span id="name-input" style="display:none"><input type="text" id="name"></span>
<span id="gender-dropdown" style="display:none">
<select id="gender">
<option></option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
</select></span>
```

Comment: Thanks Chazeon. This is exactly where I am getting stuck. When I select Gender in the dropdown, I want to display a dropdown(instead of a textbox) below with 2 options - Male and Female. Can you suggest how to incorporate this?

Comment: @Robert sorry I made a mistake, see the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. that did it.